# SQL Server: how to make a query more efficiently?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query to get the closest point from a given position.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc_getClosestPoint
    (
    @my_lat Decimal(11,8),
    @my_lng Decimal(11,8)
    )
AS
    DECLARE @my_position geography;
    SET @meu_position = geography::Point(@my_lng, @my_lat , 4326);

    SELECT TOP 1 
        idLocalGeo, 
        @my_location.STDistance(point)/1000
    FROM tLocalGeo
    ORDER BY @my_location.STDistance(point)
```

I need that query to be more efficient, for example, in this way, it has to evaluate the distance from every point, just to return one, what can I do to execute this process more quickly?

Can you provide me some tips? There are any conditions that I should know?

Thank you!

NOTE: Here is my SQL Server table

```
CREATE TABLE tLocalGeo
(
   id identity(1,1) primary key not null,
   point geography not null
)
```

Comment: use a different algorithm....

Comment: I was looking for some conditions like "IS NOT NULL", etc... but in this case doesn't need that because i will never have null points.